# How to extract velocity of some pixels from calcOpticalFlowPyrLK (OpenCV and Python version)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

I want to extract velocity vectors (velx and vely)  with optical flow  of some pixels between two frames. I am using the OpenCV function as follow:

p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, have a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to know what of how you can ask here. You should at least explain what you've tried and ask an actual question (I don't see any in your post).

Comment: You have old point locations `p0` and new corresponding point locations `p1`. The distance between them *is* the velocity of those points. Velocity is distance/time, and in this case, the time is just between frames so you don't need to do any other calculation.

Comment: Thanks Alexander Reynolds.